# How can i fix this nested isSet() php code with a switch statement inside?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Below is the code i am referring to. The problem here is that after I select a dropdown option (such as delete account/delete character), my switch statement displays a dynamically populated dropdown list(based on mysql data). However, when i try to select an option from that list and delete it, the if block (in the second code fence) never executes. I've tried a variety of workarounds and i am just at a loss of what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
<form class = "myform" action = "adminportal.php" method = "post">
            <select name = "option" required>
                <option value ="none" selected disabled hidden>Choose an Option</option>
                <option value="banacc">Delete an account</option>
                <option value="deletechar">Delete a character</option>
                <option value="update">Add gold/levels/changename</option>
            </select>
        <input type ="submit" name = "submit_search" value="submit"/>
    </form>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit_search']))
            {
                $mychoice =$_POST['option'];

                switch($mychoice)
                {
```

> this does not execute

```
                // list all the users, choose an account to ban 
                case "banacc":

                $query = "select username from userinfo";
                echo "<form action = '' method = 'POST'>";
                echo "<select name='account' value=''>Account</option>"; 
                echo"<option selected ='default' value = 'default'>Select Account</option>";
                foreach ($con->query($query) as $row) {
                    echo "<option>$row[username]</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
                echo"<input type ='submit' name = 'delete' value='delete'/></form>";


                if(isset($_POST['delete']))
                {
                    $account = $_POST['account'];
                    $query = "delete from userinfo where username = '$account'";
                    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                    if($query_run){
                            echo '<script type = "text/javascript"> alert("Purchase Successful")</script>';
                    }
                    else{
                            echo '<script type = "text/javascript"> alert("Purchase Successful")</script>';
                    }
                }

                break;
```

```
                    case "deletechar":

                    $query = "select name from characterinfo";
                    echo "<select name='character' value=''>Character</option>"; 
                    echo"<option selected ='default' value = 'default'>Select Character</option>";
                    foreach ($con->query($query) as $row) {
                        echo "<option>$row[name]</option>";
                    }
                    echo '</select>';


                    break;



                    case "update": 
                    $query = "select name from characterinfo";
                    echo "<select name='character' value=''>Character</option>"; 
                    echo"<option selected ='default' value = 'default'>Select Character</option>";
                    foreach ($con->query($query) as $row) {
                        echo "<option>$row[name]</option>";
                    }
                    echo '</select>';





                    break;
                }
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Because you only get to `if(isset($_POST['delete']))` when `if(isset($_POST['submit_search']))` is true. Place your `if(isset($_POST['delete']))` block outside of your `if(isset($_POST['submit_search']))` block

Comment: hmmm. i tried doing this, and when i apply that to the code it will only reach the "select an option" block. so far without any changes the code works for letting you select an option, and then letting you select an account but as soon as i hit "delete" nothing inside that block executes.

Comment: Keep your code as it is here in the question. Then make sure that `$_POST['submit_search']` and `$_POST['option']` are also available in your second form using hidden fields `<input type="hidden" name="submit_search">` and `<input type="hidden" name="option" value="{$_POST['option']}">`. This way your first `if` gets triggered on submission of your second form and `$_POST['option']` will be there for your `switch` statement. Hope that works ;)

Comment: Added the code and still no luck :( is there any other change of structure I could do as a workaround? So if i understand correctly, the problem is that  my first condition is triggering everytime i try to hit my "delete" button, thus sending me back to the beginning?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: "_that my first condition is triggering everytime i try to hit my "delete" button_" Nope, the other way: your first condition _only_ triggers when you submit your first form. If you hit the "delete" button, _NONE_ of your conditions get triggered because `$_POST['submit_search']` doesn't exist in your second form

Comment: Imho the "easiest" way would be to split up your code into different pages, each responsible for doing _one_ thing, `banacc.php`, `deletechar.php` and `update.php`. Your first form could be just simple links to each page with the code from your switch cases. Good luck